# Can I plug my modem to an ethernet switch for my router to use?

Tags: router, ethernet, modem, switch, gigabit-ethernet

I am trying to increase my upload speed, but I am currently using the Belkin N600DB as a router (no gigabit ethernet). I would have preferred to buy a better router altogether, but for some reason my mother will not allow me to upgrade the family router. So I have to work under these conditions.

I am using the Linksys CM3024 DOCSIS modem, which says it has gigabit ethernet. So this is where I ask my question. Can I use a switch on the modem and then plug the router to the switch? That way my mother can keep her attachment to the overpriced and badly performing Belkin N600DB while I can finally get some gigabit ethernet.

Comment: _"the router is definitely throttling our speed"_ What makes you say that? Do you have gigabit internet access? You know that gigabit ethernet does not give you gigabit internet access? Perhaps you have something in the order of 200Mbit internet, in which case you would be correct.

Comment: Have you tried the Belkin's 802.11n Wi-Fi interface? You should be able to get several times better than 100Mbit off of that.

Comment: Surely you could get your hands on a cheap or free used gigabit router - just something simple that doesn't even have wifi would be fine.  Used gigabit routers can be had on eBay for little more than the cost of postage.  Ask half a dozen people and you may even find someone with one sitting collecting dust in their closet.  You could keep and reconfigure the N600DB as an access point.

Comment: I second @J...'s idea. You can comply with your mother's constraints (i.e. "not upgrading the router") by just reconfiguring it as a switch and put your new router between the modem and router.

Answer (score 8):

No, your Linksys CM3024 is a pure DOCSIS modem (that is, it does not include any gateway/router functionality), and the DOCSIS specification doesn't allow a modem to talk to more than one device. DOCSIS modems only talk to the first MAC address they see after boot. If you had a switch connected to it, and a computer and a router connected to the switch, it would be a coin toss to see which device the modem would talk to after each reboot.

Comment: I beg to differ that this answer is incorrect in many circumstances... We have a local cable provider that services several states and uses DOCSIS 3.0 & 3.1 modems and they will hand out public IP addresses to up to ~16 devices behind the modem, not just the first device. We frequently put in a switch and "split" the internet for 2-5 routers on a single cable modem, using the switch to control QoS of the connection.

Comment: @acejavelin I'd love to know the exact manufacturer and model# of a modem and switch you've used in this setup. I strongly suspect the product you called a modem was actually acting as a DOCSIS gateway ("eRouter") not a plain DOCSIS modem.

Comment: @acejavelin I second Spiff’s comment, especially because there are increasingly a lot of hybrid devices consisting of a DOCSIS modem, Ethernet router, and wireless AP rolled into one device that are still just called a ‘modem’ by most people. Cable companies that offer internet service _love_ to rent these to their customers for some reason, despite the fact that a lot of them have serious reliability issues the moment you do anything complicated with them.

Comment: @acejavelin In cases where your ISP and hardware would allow such a thing, this would be a sketchy recommendation because it would put OP's computer directly onto the public internet with no hardware firewall (effectively a DMZ).  I remember ISPs giving out IPs like this maybe twenty years ago, but I'd doubt this works in many places now. This would also complicate home networking since OP would be effectively on a separate network from everyone else going through the router.

Comment: IIRC, Comcast used to offer multiple IPs for an extra cost, but I think they've gotten rid of that for residential customers; if you need it, you have to get Comcast Business.

Comment: Well that explains why I used to have to spoof one computer's MAC address when switching the cable to a different computer, back in the days before home routers, when it was unusual to have two computers, but after cable Internet.

Comment: Modems are supplied by the ISP, but typically Hitron CDA3-35, Hitron CODA-45/46/47, or Cisco DCP3010 are the most common ones. We use Cisco SG3xx switches with isolated VLAN to switch the ISP connection, using an uplink to the modem, an uplink to our Meraki router, and another uplink to the customers existing data router is a typical scenario. I don't advocate for putting a PC directly on the public internet side of this connection, a second router would be needed... My point was that although the answer may apply, I can guarantee it doesnt apply in all cases.

Answer (score 3):

#### Use a Second Router

Not ideal, but really not that unusual. Put a gigabit router between the modem and the N600DB. To avoid confusion (and "being found out"), get a router that does **not** have WiFi - a small gigabit router with no WiFi won't look much different from a switch. Set it up with a **different** subnet from the existing router. The new router will get an external IP address from the modem and provide IP addresses within the designated subnet to your computer and to the N600DB. The N600DB should be set up for simple DHCP for the external address (it may be different in the current configuration).

The only drawbacks are:

- Your computer won't be able to share any printers or other devices that are connected to the N600DB, unless you map ports to those devices through the N600DB.
- If you need external access to any devices on the N600DB, you will need to map ports through **both** routers.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I misread this as putting the new device *downstream* of the Belkin, not upstream (as I'd have expected an answer basically saying the poster can do what they asked if they can do to start with something like "Yes").